# RestAssured certificate issue

Tags: java, web-services, ssl-certificate, soapui, rest-assured

I have configured webservices in Soapui and added .jks file with password in SSL Keystore in the soapui settings and I was able to successfuly post the message with a positive response.

I am trying to replicate it with RestAssured using below code

```
resBuilder= new RequestSpecBuilder();
resBuilder.setKeyStore(cert,password);
resBuilder.setRelaxedHTTPSValidation(); 
RequestSpecification requestSpec = resBuilder.build();
            response = given()
            .spec(requestSpec)
            .when()
            .post(url);
            da.addResponses(response);
```

When i execute the code, i am getting below error

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <env:Fault>
      <faultcode>No SSL Certificate Sent By Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Authorization Failure</faultstring>
    </env:Fault>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <env:Fault>
      <faultcode>No SSL Certificate Sent By Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Authorization Failure</faultstring>
    </env:Fault>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I tried to create trust store but chrome show certificate as invalid and not sure how to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

got same error recently.After some research I figured out that requestSpec.relaxedHttpsValidation() works for me but requestSpecBuilder.setRelaxedHTTPSValidation() not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).